# Wordpress blog Android app

Tags: android, wordpress

I was wondering if there was an open source project for a Wordpress Android app ? I don't want to administrate Wordpress via the app, just make them available for my users to browse my news via an app. I would need the code to adapt it and I don't want just a webview, although what I want is pretty simple (4 tabs, and a tab for news the rest for static pages).

I searched on the net and I couldn't find anything, looking at how many people use WP, I thought someone might have come with an app that they d be willing to share ?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of Wordpress plugins out there that will convert your site into a native or html5 based mobile app for several different platforms.  You can find a list of some of the Android ones here:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/android

UppSite looks like a pretty easy one to use.

Comment: Thanks but I don't wanna use a third party. I strictly said I would need the .apk file to adapt it as much as I want.